# Given a point, determine a direction to stay on the same "height" of a function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I am given $f(x,y) = y \cos(πx) - x \cos(πy)$, and I am standing on the point (2,1,3). I am asked to give a direction so that along that direction I maintain my height. My thought process is: $ \nabla f(2,1)$ gives me the vector (and direction) which I should follow to leave my height as quickly as possible, so I will find the vector orthogonal to it.

I solved for the gradient and found that $\nabla f(2,1) = (1,1)$ and thus, I let $\vec{u} = (x,y)$, such that $\nabla f(2,1) \cdot \vec{u} = 0$ and found $y = -x$ so that is the direction on which I don't change my height. Is that correct? Am I thinking right?

Comment: Your intuition is correct. However, you should prove that **if you can maintain a height in a direction (or to phrase it in another way if the surface contains a line passing through a given point)** then the direction of that line is perpendicular to the gradient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, you are. Just to check, note that$$f(2+t,1-t)-f(2,1)=3\bigl(\cos(\pi t)-1\bigr),$$and if we differentiate this expression at $0$, then we get $0$.

To see that that's always the case, suppose that, for some differentible function $g$, $\nabla g(x_0,y_0)=(a,b)$. Consider the function $\gamma(t)=g(x_0+bt,y_0-at)-g(x_0,y_0)$. Then\begin{align}\gamma'(0)&=\bigl\langle\nabla g(x_0,y_0),(-b,a)\bigr\rangle\\&=\bigl\langle(a,b),(-b,a)\bigr\rangle\\&=0.\end{align}